# Learning OB DAL Programming

Tags: openbravo

Is there any book available on DAL programming for Openbravo.I tried to search on Wiki about dal program but couldn't find in details. I like to know more about syntax details and its explanation.

Regards
Usman A.

Answer (score 1):

there is actually quite a few resources on this topic on Openbravo's wiki, for example:

- http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Data_Access_Layer
- http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_do_a_complex_query_using_the_DAL-1
- http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_do_a_complex_query_using_the_DAL-2

Keep in mind that the Openbravo DAL is just an extension of the [Hibernate ORM](http://hibernate.org/orm/) so most of the same concepts and syntax apply.

Hope this helps.
Rok

Comment: Hi Rok, Thanks for your reply. Honestly the wiki links on DAL is not straight forward and easy to follow for novice and beginners like me especially who also learning Java. I will explore Hibernate ORM. Regards, Usman A.